# Exceptions to violate Dry principle

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm a fixing a bug related to a missing mouse event and there are 2 ways to fix it. One of them looks efficient and requires one line of code change(I know that less code has nothing to do with efficiency). The other one looks better for code readability & documentation but it violates DRY principle.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function() {
  //some code here was removed
  events: {
    'tap tbody.classX': 'triggerTap'
  }
}

triggerTap: function(e) {
  console.log('do your job');
}
```

First suggested fix by adding a mouse event listener which triggers the same method, the tap event triggers.

```
function() {
  events: {
    'tap tbody.classX': 'triggerTap',
    'click tbody.classX': 'triggerTap'
  }
}
```

Second suggested fix by adding another method (`triggerMouseClick`) which does the same exact thing as `triggerTap`

```
function() {
  events: {
    'tap tbody.classX': 'triggerTap',
    'click tbody.classX': 'triggerMouseClick'
  }
}

//triggerTap method
triggerTap: function(e) {
  console.log('do your job');
}

//trigger mouse click
triggerMouseClick: function(e) {
  console.log('do your job');

}
```

Comment: Your `function` syntax is invalid. You seem to be confusing functions with object literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in adding another function that does the same thing. That is code duplication.

On the other hand invoking a function called `triggerTap` on mouse click isn't readable as well.

The correct thing to do here is to rename `triggerTap` to a meaningful name, something that makes sense for both, like `triggerTapAndClick` or better something that refers to the action that tap and mouse click does. For example:

```
function() {
  events: {
    'tap tbody.classX': 'openContactsList',
    'click tbody.classX': 'openContactsList'
  }
}

openContactsList: function(e) {
  console.log('do your job');
}
```